# Python capturing success or failure in subprocess

Tags: python, curl

Here is the snippet of python code. I am trying to get the result of curl command. (Note: i could use requests module instead of calling curl command, but for some complexity reasons, which request module didnt work out, I ended up using the command)

I am capturing the curl output using subprocess and storing the success/error output in stdout and stderr. In this case, I see the script prints both Success and failure. However, finally, I want to get either success/error depending on results, not both. Can someone please throw some light on what could be wrong here

```
counter = 1
for url in urls:
    command = 'curl ' + acceptance_url
    args = command.split()
    process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()


    if stdout is not None:
        print "Success: %s" % (stdout)


    if stderr is not None:
        print "Error: %s" %(stderr)
```

Comment: Its generally easier to use `subprocess.run` than `Popen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command fails, then the stdout contain empty string ("") and not `None`.
So instead of checking for None return, check for empty string.

```
import subprocess
counter = 1
command = 'curl www.google.com'
args = command.split()
process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

if stdout != "":
    print "stdout: " + str(stdout)


if stdout == "":
    print "stderr: " + str(stderr)
```

Code Output:

```
$ python temp.py 
stdout: <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=1LASWeGTCcb38AfshbDoCQ">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>

$ # curl www.goovadvgle.com
$ python temp.py 
stderr:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.goovadvgle.com

$
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't check if it's not None, convert it to a positive expression:

```
if stdout:
   print "Success: %s" % (stdout)

if stderr:
   print "Error: %s" %(stderr)
```

You could also check the

> Popen.returncode: The child return code, set by poll() and wait() (and
>   indirectly by communicate()).

to see if the command was successful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) for this task

```
try:
    print( subprocess.check_output(args) )
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as ee:
    print(ee.output)
```